# Mutation is not set value no state - Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, quasar-framework

Mutation is not set value no state.

The problem is that the state is not being updated.

What I'm doing wrong.

Mutation

```
function cardValidationSet (state, data) {
  state.cardValided = data
}
```

Getters

```
function cardValidationget (state) {
  return state.cardValided
}
```

Component A

```
import Store from '../store'

display: function () {
     Store().commit('disponivel/cardValidationSet', valided)
}
```

Component B

```
import { mapGetters, mapActions, mapMutations } from 'vuex'

computed: {
    ...mapGetters('disponivel', ['cardValidationget'])
  },
methods: {
onSubmitPay () {
      console.log(this.cardValidationget)
    },
}
```

[image]

Comment: try to remove `()` from `Store()...`

Comment: [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _store__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.default.commit is not a function"

Comment: Are you exporting a function from the `../store` module? If it's a factory then `Store()` is probably instantiating a new store instance. Can you show us your store code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have setup Vuex properly, the right way to commit a mutation is

```
 this.$store.commit('disponivel/cardValidationSet', valided)
```